# yii2: geometry type column in migration table

Tags: yii2

I'm learning Yii2 framework. There's a [geometry type column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZe3y.jpg) in my MySQL table. I was wondering if I could create it with a Yii2 migration table. Unfortunately, there is no such `geometry()` method in [yii\db\SchemaBuilderTrait](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-schemabuildertrait.html) class so I assume the following won't work:

```
 $this->createTable('{{%gps}}', [
            ...

            'gps' => $this->geometry()->notNull()       

            ...
 ]);
```

Does anyone know any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used for create a geometry but you can also use an hash format for create column

```
use yii\db\Schema;
use yii\db\Migration;




    $this->createTable('Your_table ', [ 
        'id' =>  'pk',
        'user_id' =>  'integer not null',             
        'land_scope_code' => 'string(4)',    
        'init_lat' => 'decimal(24,20)',
        'init_lng' => 'decimal(24,20)',
        'init_zoom' => 'integer',

    ]);
```

could be this is useful for your

```
$this->createTable('{{%gps}}', [
        ...

        'gps' => 'geometry not null';       

        ...
]);
```